# How to add custom code in mailers ? adding ruby code in @message variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code /app/mailers/email_mailer.rb

```
@message = message.content
```

and I want to add some ruby string to it at the end of the message like

```
@message = message.content + <%= link_to 'Home Page!', root_url %>
```

so the urls gets shown below the email message but I am getting syntax error, I am sure I am missing something very small, any help ?

EDIT - I tried this code too which is not throwing error by the Home Page link is not adding to the @message

```
@message = message.content.to_s + '<%= link_to "Home Page!", root_url %>'
```

Comment: Please add information about context of this code. do you run it inside ActionMailer method or in mailer template?

Comment: @gvalmon - yes I am running it in /app/mailers/email_mailer.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this into mailer template into `app/views/email_mailer` dir & into `YOUR_MAILER_NAME_HERE.html.erb` file

```
<%= @message %>
<%= link_to 'Home Page!', root_url %>
```